# How to root ATT gs4(SGH-I337) in 4.4.2

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I want to root my s4 and I was waiting for kingoroot to develop a root method for 4.4.2 but I was wondering whether there are other one click root methods out there that are low - risk of bricking. If you know any that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and run [Towelroot](http://towelroot.com/). It Worked perfectly on my At&T S4 KitKat 4.4.2 SGH-1337 that I could not root before.

Comment: Yep, already used it and rooted about 2 weeks or so back but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, the only root method for the AT&T S4 4.4.2 is via a convoluted flashing method detailed on [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2692825).  It's definitely not low-risk, nor anywhere close to one-click.  Additionally, a new update is supposedly rolling out, so this may complicate things even further.